# How to hash password before saving user in node js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my user model:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 1024,
    min: 6
  }
});

schema.pre("save", async next => {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(erro);
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

when i save user, it return empty object and it doesn't save and not working.
i don't know what should to do?
what is the problem?

Comment: It looks right to me.. only thing I can see, though is that you are doing `return next()` - I don't think that should matter, but try just doing `next()` without the `return`... I can see 3 different times that you are doing this.

Comment: I suppose it's possible this line is messing with it? `if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();` try to comment that line out as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use function form instead of arrow function inside the pre save middleware.
Because Arrow functions do not bind their own this.

```js
schema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks it works, but what is i want to use arrow function?

Comment: @ShaSha in this case you can’t use arrow function.